# Suppress initial when using Cursor.observeChanges

Tags: meteor

With the following code, all 10 existing records will be echoed out. However I am expecting `observeChanges` to only print out the new records.

How can this be done? And why is it returning all the existing docs in the query?

`added` is also not executed when new docs are inserted. Unless we remove the `limit` operator.

**server.js**

```
var query = myCollection.find({}, {limit: 10})

query.observeChanges({
    _suppress_initial: true,

    added: function (id, fields) {
        console.log('doc added')
    }
})
```

Using Meteor 0.7.0.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new meteor versions ( 0.7 and later) that phase in oplog tailing no longer support _suppress_initial.  Brief mention of the [change here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/meteor-talk/_suppress_initial%7Csort%3arelevance%7Cspell%3afalse/meteor-talk/MMcwwn_zRrg/7AESx3hu7uEJ) and that it might come back in some form.

Update:  If you want log to console whenever something new gets inserted into 'myCollection' then this would work:

```
var query = myCollection.find({}); //find everything in collection currently
var init = true;

query.observeChanges({

  added: function (id, fields) {
      if ( ! init) 
        console.log('doc added');
  }
});

init = false;
```

With limit, if the collection starts with more than 10 documents, the cursor will just keep finding the same 10 original documents so while collection grows by inserting that cursor does not need to grow beyond 10 docs.

Comment: Any idea on how we can manually workaround the lack of `_suppress_initial`?

Comment: That is probably an interesting question on its own.  The counts-by-room example tracks initialising with a variable set to true before the observe and then set to false afterwards.  It says "Observe only returns after the initial added callbacks have run." so copying that method might work for a lot of cases.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to avoid firing the added function multiple times for the initial load is to debounce it.
With Underscore:

```
query.observeChanges({

  added: _.debounce(function(id, fields) {
    // Do something
  }, 100)

});
```